# how to force redirect from http to https with htaccess?

Tags: apache-httpd, http, https, htaccess

I need to force, with htaccess, redirect from http to https of a website.

Required when use shared hosting like dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

For force redirect I use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.us/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ https://domain.us/ [R,L]
```

redirect domain.us -> https://domain.us

and

redirect domain.us/sub/ -> https://domain.us/sub/